# Rails routes for cms cms powered site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I've been away from Rails for a while but I have a site that is running on rails where I have created a page editor. I need some help with my routes.

I want to have something like this for my URL on the front end of the site:

//domain/welcome/pagename/page or //domain/welcome/page/pagename

Then within the welcome_controller I have this:

```
def page
# I provide the user with the a page
@mypage = Contents.find_by_name(params[:pagename])
end
```

Then within the page view itself I can render aspects of the @mypage record as I see fit.

However, I need some help with the routes to get this all working the way I intend.

Currently, I have this for my welcome route:

```
  resources :welcome do
     collection do
        get :site
        get :home
        get :page
        get :thankyou
        post :newslettersignup
        post :sendcontact
      end
    end
```

I know that I need more... Just now sure exactly what it should be.

Any help would greatly be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use non-resourceful routing to do this easily:

```
get '/welcome/:pagename/site', to: 'welcome#site'
get '/welcome/:pagename/home', to: 'welcome#home'
get '/welcome/:pagename/page', to: 'welcome#page'
get '/welcome/:pagename/thankyou', to: 'welcome#thankyou'
post '/welcome/:pagename/newslettersignup', to: 'welcome#newslettersignup'
post '/welcome/:pagename/sendcontact', to: 'welcome#sendcontact'
```

The `:pagename` syntax allows the value of that segment of the URL to be included in `params[:pagename]`. The `to: 'welcome#site'` bit means, "Route this to the `WelcomeController#site` action."

Please see [Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) for a great reference when working with routes.